# Rewrite proposition with logical symbols

Tags: solution-verification, determinant, quadratics, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I want to rewrite the following proposition in mathematical language (and by mathematical language I mean symbols such as: $\forall , \exists, (, ), \implies$ and so on).

**Proposition:** Every non-trivial quadratic equation with real coefficients and whose determinant is positive has two different solutions.

**My attempt:** $$\forall a, b, c,x\in\mathbb{R}\exists y=ax^2+bx+c\left[\left(a\neq 0~ \land ~b^2-4ac>0\right)\implies\left(x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)\right]$$

I think this might be wrong but that is what I have done so far. In case my attempt is wrong, then how can I solve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Some hints: There're 2 *different* solutions, we can call them $x_1$ and $x_2$. Also, there's no need to use the quadratic formula. For example, $x_1$ is a solution simply means $a x_1^2 + b x_1 + c = 0$. Basically, the answer would look like $$\forall a, b, c \in \mathbb{R} \ (\dots) \implies (\exists x_1, x_2 \ (\dots))$$ There might be other ways to do it, but this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be written as follows.

$$\forall a, b, c,x\in\mathbb{R}\left[
\begin{array}{l}
\left(ax^2+bx+c=0\wedge a\neq 0 \wedge b^2-4ac>0\right)\implies\\
\exists x_1\in\mathbb{R}\exists x_2\in\mathbb{R}(x_1\neq x_2 \wedge a{x_1}^2+bx_1+c=0\wedge a{x_2}^2+bx_2+c=0)
\end{array}
\right].$$

More accurately, it should be written as follows where $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0)$ is a first order structure.

$$(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0)\vDash\forall a, b, c\left[
\begin{array}{l}
\left(ax^2+bx+c=0\wedge a\neq 0 \wedge b^2-4ac>0\right)\implies\\
\exists x_1\exists x_2(x_1\neq x_2 \wedge a{x_1}^2+bx_1+c=0\wedge a{x_2}^2+bx_2+c=0)
\end{array}
\right].$$